# pandas concat infinite loop

Tags: pandas, concatenation

I am trying to concat a column from one DF with 0.5 m rows with another DF but it goes into an infinite loop.
In fact there is a for loop on a series of df where each will hold a summary column from another df

the code is:

```
    from timeit import default_timer as timer
start = timer()
for s in NEM.keys():
    F = s[0]
    print(F)
    cols=NEM[s].shape[1]
    stateW = wind_output.loc[:,wind_output.columns.str.startswith(F)].copy()
    stateW["rsum"]=stateW.sum(axis=1)
    #NEM[s].insert(cols,"wsum","")
    p = NEM[s].copy()
    print("state rows are ",len(p))
    print("wind output rows are ",len(stateW))
    p["wsum"]=stateW["rsum"]
    **strong text**j=pd.concat([p.copy(),stateW["rsum"]], axis=1)**
    NEM[s]=j.copy()
end = timer()
print()
print("The time taken is ", end - start)
```

without the concat line the code runs in less than 1 second. when the concat line is included the loop does not complete an iteration in 10 minutes

i used similar concat lines in other places and it was almost instantaneous as I'd expect.

Suggestions much appreciated. I am a novice at pandas really.

Comment: `concat` in a loop is very slow. Collect the items in a list and merge **once** after the loop

Answer (score 0):

Hi I'd like to mark the question solved. I was using ambiguous indexes. After that was resolved the concat was as fast as one could wish.